# Can't Pass function to child Object in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

I am trying to pass a function to a child wisget in Flutter. The child widget should return the index of the pressed button via this function.

The child widget is a side menu (drawer) and depending on which menu is selected, the page in the parent widget should be changed. However, the problem is that I can't call the method I passed to the child widget because the following error occurs as soon as I call it:
`Expected a value of type '() => void', but got one of type 'Null'`

Important is, that I want to handle the value in the Parent Widget and retrieve it from the child.

Parent Widget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        exit(0);
      },

      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: SideMenu(
          onMemberPressed: (int value) {
            // onMemberPressed(value);
            print(value);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Child Widget (Drawer):

```
class SideMenu extends StatelessWidget {

  final Function(int) onMemberPressed;

  const SideMenu({
    super.key,
    required this.onMemberPressed,
  });



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      elevation: 10,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topRight: Radius.circular(0),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(0),
        ),
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              child: Image.asset("lib/images/logo.png",),
            ),
            //Anzeige der Mitglieder und ein widget zum hinzufügen von Mitgliedern
            DrawerListTile(title: "Dashboard", icon: Icons.dashboard, onTap: () {}),
            //Anzeige der Mitglieder und ein widget zum hinzufügen von Mitgliedern
            DrawerListTile(title: "Member", icon: Icons.group, onTap: onMemberPressed(1)),
            //Anzeige der Teams und ein widget zum hinzufügen von Teams
            DrawerListTile(title: "Teams", icon: Icons.groups, onTap: () {}),
            //Anzeige der User und ein widget zum hinzufügen von admins und Mdoeratoren
            DrawerListTile(title: "User", icon: Icons.person, onTap: () {}),
            //Anzeige des eigenen Nutzers um den Verein zu verlassen
            DrawerListTile(
                title: "Comming Soon", icon: Icons.block, onTap: () {}),
          ])),
    );
  }
}

class DrawerListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const DrawerListTile({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.icon,
    required this.onTap,
  });

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: onTap,
      horizontalTitleGap: 0,
      leading: Icon(
        icon,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 16,
      ),
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wrong to do

```
onTap: onMemberPressed(1)
```

because this assigns the result of `onMemberPressed(1)` to `onTap`. So you need to do this instead

```
onTap: () => onMemberPressed(1)
```